# redirect to correct angular route in html5mode with rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, angular-ui-router

I removed the `'#'` in `angular` using `html5Mode` and it works but when I refresh its looking for the template in rails instead of angular and throwing the template not found error.

**angular route**

```
app.config([
    "$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider","$locationProvider",
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state("home", {
                url: "/",
                controller: "homeCtrl",
                templateUrl: "angular/templates/home.html"
            })
            .state("/dashboard", {
                url: "/dashboard",
                templateUrl: "angular/templates/dashboard/dashboard.html"
            })
            .state("/dashboard.active", {
                url: "/active",
                templateUrl: "angular/templates/dashboard/active.html",
                controller: "activeCtrl"
            })
            .state("/dashboard.inactive", {
                url: "/inactive",
                templateUrl: "angular/templates/dashboard/inactive.html",
                controller: "inactiveCtrl"
            })
            .state("/dashboard.drafts", {
                url: "/drafts",
                templateUrl: "angular/templates/dashboard/drafts.html",
                controller: "draftsCtrl",
                resolve: {
                    drafts: function (DashboardFactory) {
                        return DashboardFactory.drafts();
                    }
                }
            })
            .state("/room", {
                url: "/rooms/:id",
                templateUrl: "angular/templates/rooms/show.html",
                controller: "roomsCtrl",
                resolve: {
                    room: function (RoomFactory, $stateParams) {
                        var roomId = $stateParams.id;
                        return RoomFactory.show(roomId);
                    }
                }
            })
            .state("/search", {
                url: "/search?:latitude&:longitude",
                templateUrl: "angular/templates/search.html",
                controller: "searchCtrl",
                resolve: {
                    search: function (SearchFactory, $stateParams) {
                        var latitude = $stateParams.latitude;
                        var longitude = $stateParams.longitude;
                        return SearchFactory.search(latitude, longitude);
                    }
                }
            })
            .state("/conversations", {
                url: "/conversations",
                templateUrl: "angular/templates/conversations/conversations.html",
                controller: "conversationsCtrl",
                resolve: {
                    conversations: function (ConversationFactory) {
                        return ConversationFactory.showConversations();
                    }
                }
            })
            .state("/messages", {
                url: "/conversations/:id/messages",
                templateUrl: "angular/templates/conversations/messages.html",
                controller: "messagesCtrl",
                resolve: {
                    conversations: function (ConversationFactory, $stateParams) {
                        var conversationId = $stateParams.id;
                        return ConversationFactory.showMessages(conversationId);
                    }
                }
            })
            .state("/notifications", {
                url: "/notifications",
                templateUrl: "angular/templates/notifications/notifications.html",
                controller: "notificationsCtrl",
                resolve: {
                    notifications: function (NotificationFactory) {
                        return NotificationFactory.getNotifications();
                    }
                }
            });

        // use the HTML5 History API
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }
]);
```

**Rails route**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  require 'sidekiq/web'
  mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'

  devise_for :users,
             :path => '',
             :path_names => {:edit => 'profile'},
             :controllers => {:registrations => 'registrations'}
  resource :pages, only: [:edit] do
    collection do
      patch 'update_password'
    end
  end

  resources :conversations, only: [:create, :index] do
    resources :messages, only: [:create, :index]
  end

  resources :notifications do
    collection do
      post :mark_as_read
    end
  end


  root 'pages#home'
  get '/general' => 'pages#general'
  get '/drafts' => 'rooms#drafts'
  get '/active' => 'rooms#active_listings'
  get '/inactive' => 'rooms#inactive_listings'
  get '/search' => 'pages#search'
  get '/change_password' => 'pages#change_password'



  resources :rooms do
    post :make_active
    post :make_inactive
    resources :photos, only: [:index, :create, :destroy]
  end

  mount ImageUploader.direct_endpoint, at: "/attachments/images"

end
```

Also in `application.html.erb` I have set the base to   `<base href="/">`..

If its the route page(`localhost:3000`) page refresh works..But if its the search page `http://localhost:3000/search` or any other page it wont work.

But when not using the `html5mode` everything works fine. Am I doing something wrong here?? What is the correct approach to follow here??

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Ruby on Rails, but from an Angular/JS application standpoint, this usually happens when you haven't specified which page to serve for unregistered routes. Usually this problem is fixed by making sure that index.html is the page served for all unspecified routes.

Comment: @Himmel It is not a pure full angular app and has few html pages aswell. I think I need to custom write each route on rails side..

Answer (score 0):

You can disable requireBase property as below.

```
 $locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
  });
```

And please specify $routeProvider.otherwise("home"). also. It should work.

Comment: I have done that in my application.html.erb and is mentioned in question aswell..